# Changing style sheets not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I've got a style sheet changer with javascript but it doesn't work in IE while working good in Firefox and Chrome. The HTML code I'm using is this:

```
<head>

<link href="defualt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme1.css" title="theme1" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme2.css" title="theme2" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme3.css" title="theme3" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css"  />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <select id="myList" >
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="theme1">Theme 1</option>
        <option value="theme2">Theme 2</option>  
        <option value="theme3">Theme 3</option>
    </select>
</form>

</body>
```

And the javascript:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
    var i, a, main;
    for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
        if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
            a.disabled = true;
            if (a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
        }
    }
    createCookie("style", title, 7);
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
    var i, a;
    for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
        if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
    }
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
    var i, a;
    for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
        if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
           && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
           && a.getAttribute("title")
           ) return a.getAttribute("title");
    }
}

function getTheme() {
    var storedThemeVal = readCookie('selectedTheme');
    if (storedThemeVal != null && storedThemeVal != "") {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) {
            if (selectBox.options[i].value == storedThemeVal) {
                selectBox.selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

function setTheme() {
    var selectedThemeVal = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    createCookie('selectedTheme', selectedThemeVal);
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}



function initiate()
{

    window.selectBox = document.getElementById("myList");
    var cookie = readCookie("style");
    var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
    setActiveStyleSheet(title);
    getTheme();
    selectBox.onchange = function () {
        setActiveStyleSheet(this.value);
        setTheme();
    };





}

window.onload = initiate;
```

I can't understand why this won't work in IE since it's working so good in the other browsers. And I prefer to keep all my javascript in my separate document javascript.js as well as I don't want to work with a library.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether there is any other wrong in your code.but i know getElementsByClassName() is not supported lt IE9,and in ie,to the event binding method is attachEvent().I hope it can help u.

Comment: Can you give any example on how I can use this instead? I'm pretty new to javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Probably because IE has issues getting non-standard attributes from elements.

Also you might want to try the following instead of 'getElementsByClassName()' (not supported)

```
i = 0;
a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
while (element = a[i++]) {
  if (element.className == "sidemenu-maincat") {
    // blah blah...
  }
}
```

Comment: That part of the code wasn't even suppose to be there, made a bit of a mistake there but thanks for the guidance since I have the same problem there as well.

Comment: You don't have any solution on how to do it of the other part of the code?

Comment: Ive tried this here and works fine in IE9, also you have noticed the spelling right? <link href="defualt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Had to allow activex controls though.

Comment: Can you give me an example to work after? I'm really bad at understanding this code since I'm new with javascript..

Comment: What in particular? This is working in IE9 without changing your code.

Comment: Nevermind, was some hickups in the code I was running. Works now. I'll update the question on the other part that made it not work instead.